# Non-decreasing functions satisfying functional inequalities $f(1+ax)\leq a f(1+x)$ and $f(xy)\leq f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-inequalities

Can we exactly determine a class of non-decreasing functions defined on the set of non-negative real numbers satisfying:
$$f(1+ax)\leq a f(1+x)$$ and $$f(xy)\leq f(x)+f(y)$$
for any $x,y\in [0,\infty)$, assuming that $a\in[0,1)$ can vary?
Par example, log fulfills second inequality, but not the first one...
Looking for any kind of input or advice. (or book to look for some results on this topic)

Comment: @TheoBendit   The function $f(x)=0$ identically satisfies both conditions.  Granted, not a terribly interesting solution, but it is a solution.  Note that $f(1)≤af(1)$ for $0≤a<1$ only tells you that $f(1)≤0$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "assuming that $a$ can vary". Do you mean that for all $a,x$ such that $a \in [0,1)$ and $x \ge 0$, the first inequality holds? Or do you mean that $a$ is a parameter of the problem that lies in $[0,1),$ such that the first inequality holds for that fixed value of $a$, and that you'd like to understand the solutions possible as $a$ varies?

Comment: $f(x)=\log (1+x)$ is a solution, with $a=.5$  for example (or for other $a$).

Comment: I think the first inequality has to hold for all $0\le a<1$.

Comment: I'm pretty confident the class of functions you're looking for is zero for positive values and any non-positive value at zero.

Answer (score 0):

We establish the following claim.

**CLAIM**: Let $f:\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function.
Then $f$ satisfies all of the following conditions if and only if $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ge 0$.

1. The function $f$ is non-decreasing.
2. For all $a\in[0,1)$ we have $f(1+ax)\le af(1+x)$.
3. for all $x,y\ge 0$ we have $f(xy)\le f(x)+f(y)$.

First, notice that the all-zero function satisfies all three conditions.
Conversely, assume that all three conditions hold for $f$. By the second condition for $a=0$ we have $f(1)\le 0$, so by the first condition we have $f(x)\le 0$ for $x\le 1$. Assume that $f(0)<0$, then we get a contradiction with the third condition for $x=y=0$, so we have $f(0)=0$. By the first condition we have $f(x)=0$ for $0\le x\le 1$.

Also, by the first condition we have $f(x)\ge 0$ for $x>1$. Now, assume there exists $v>0$ such that $f(1+v)>0$. By the third condition for $x=y=1+v$ we have $f((1+v)^2)\le 2f(1+v)$. But for $x=(1+v)^2-1$ and $a=v/x$ we have
$$af(1+x)\le \frac{v}{2v+v^2}\cdot 2f(1+v)<f(1+v)=f(1+ax).$$
This violates the first condition, so for all $v>0$ we have $f(1+v)=0$, which completes the proof.

Comment: This proof uses that $f$ is defined for $0$ (and is finite). Hence, in this setup we cannot consider the logarithm. This is crucial in the second part of the proof, where we use the third condition to establish $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 1$.